# SendGrid in .NET Core Class Library

Tags: c#, .net-core, sendgrid

I have a .NET Core class library -- .NET Core 1.1 app. I installed the SendGrid NuGet package but it doesn't seem to be working as the `using` lines are grayed out. Here's the package reference in the `csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.0.12" />
```

Is there anything else I need to install?

Here's my using lines:

[image]

As you can see, I can't declare a SendGridAPIClient:

[image]

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

UPDATE:
Changing the client to SendGridClient did help but SendGrid.Helpers.Mail is still grayed out and the following method is not working:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `SendGridClient`?

Comment: I ported this code from my class library targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. It's SendGridAPIClient there and I've been using that code for quite some time.

Comment: But now you're running a newr version, the example project seems to suggest I am correct https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/ExampleCoreProject/Example.cs#L20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the project repo, and the [official example project for .Net Core](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/ExampleCoreProject/Example.cs#L20) the correct name for the object you are trying to create is actually `SendGridClient`:

```
protected static SendGridClient _client;
```

Note that the reason the `using` statements are grayed out is simply because they are considered to be unneeded since none of the code below is using anything in those namespaces. Once you are using any object from there, they will turn white.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you're right about SendGridClient. Still having other issues though. I posted a screen shot on the original post.

Comment: Looks like there are quite a few changes in the SendGrid client

Comment: Indeed, you will need to do a bit of rewriting I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I see that :-) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, I see that it's now much more intuitive. Sending a single message to multiple recipients was not very straight forward before. I guess, it's now just a matter of using multiple `msg.AddTo(email)` lines.